# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'token' in undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

I'm new to vue.js and this trying to make a navbar component, which shows a `Login` button, when the user is not authenticated. Here is the code:

```
<template>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div v-if="token">
        <br>
        <router-link to="/login">
          <button> Login</button>              
        </router-link>
      </div>


        <router-link to="/" >
          <img  class="img-responsive" src="../assets/img/logo.png">
        </router-link>  
      </div>    
</div>



  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Navbar',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },

  data: function() {

  },

  computed: {
    token () {
      return this.$store.getToken; 
    },

  },

}
</script>
```

However, I get this error in the console:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3456 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'token' in undefined
    at initComputed (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3456)
    at initState (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3311)
    at VueComponent.Vue._init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4624)
    at new VueComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4794)
    at createComponentInstanceForVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4306)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4127)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5604)
    at createElm (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5551)
    at createChildren (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5678)
    at createElm (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5580)
```

The `token` is defined in the store's tate, and `getToken` is defined in the store as:

```
getters: {
    getToken: state => {
        return state.token;
    }
},
```

If I removed the `comuted` part, I get this warning instead:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "token" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: this error may come not from the getter, how do you set token in store with mutations?

Comment: I do this in store's mutation: `setToken: function (state, token) {   state.token = token;},`

Comment: do you define token in initial state eg : `token: null` ?

Comment: Yes, initially I set it in store's state as: `token: '',` and set it in Registration component as `this.$store.commit('setToken', res.data.token);`

Comment: shouldn't it be `this.$store.getters.getToken` in computed ?

Comment: That results in the same error. I also tried `return this.$store.state.token; ` but get the same error.

Comment: Its either you try to get 'token' from some undefined field or set to some undefined field somewhere. If you use Vue.set() , make sure you pass 3 required args `.set(obj, 'propName', val)` correctly.
btw your template has extra </div> , even though its probably not the case

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Actually the extra div is left over after some clean up that I made before posting the question.

Comment: I removed `data` part and the error is gone! Apparently the empty data causes problems?!

Comment: please provide the whole code of your store